# .htaccess issues in wordpress subdomain URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

i am using below htaccess code to run sub-domain successfully,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /questions/
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.admissiontimes\.com\.nz$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) http://admissiontimes.com/questions/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /questions/index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
```

Only homepage is working fine, all other links redirecting to homepage only,if i am clicking in Sign up, its took my to home page only, as base URL has been changed to http://www.domainname.com/questions/sign-up/ . Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would reccomend you to use redirection plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/ on your wordpress installation instead of manual .htaccess edit. It is simple and easy to use and you can also add Regx to your redirects.

Comment: I am not in need to redirect the domain, my domain is successfully running on my domain name www.yourdomain.com (wordpress), need to run its subdomain as well. Everything is running fine, but only pages of subdomain did not work well. Have a glimpse on my domain url http://www.admissiontimes.com/questions/, click on Sign up/Sign IN. Might be you would gets my point clearly. Thankyou

Comment: Any Help ?  I am in big trouble due to this

Comment: I think maybe the problem is with your theme. Try using some other theme and see if it is fixed. Just try to figure out the actual problem.